# Set Session in Joomla Login

Tags: session, joomla

I am using `Joomla 3.0` the latest version, I need to delete the `session` once the user gets logged in, i am not in mood to `login` in again with the same user ID--- Hence the session in Joomla retrieve by `$session =& JFactory::getSession();`

Any idea how can i set up the username so that he can only `logged` in once on the website ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this,

```
$user    = JFactory::getUser();
$session =& JFactory::getSession();

$session->set('userid',$user->id);

//checking whether the user logged in or not
$userid = $session->get('userid');
if($userid=='')
{
   $session->set('userid','');  //set to blank
}
```